# Visual Studio Preview 2015 is missing "VS Emulator Android Phone"

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Being exited with the new release of VS preview I downloaded and installed it.

I wanted to try out the new Android Emulator and created a new Cordova project. I was expecting similar choices listed in this screenshot:
[image]

However I was only presented with the first five (Device, Android Emulator, Ripple ...) but missing VS Emulator Android Phone and VS Emulator Android Tablet.

If I try to run the application using option "Android Emulator" I get the following error in the output console:

```
2>    WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to MonoForAndroid_API_10
2>  Waiting for emulator...
2>  emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
```

Should the Android Emulator be included in the VS 2015 Preview release, or do I have to install something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android is installed by a secondary installer that should pop up after installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Preview. There should have been an item in that list that needed to be checked.

If you can verify in Add/Remove Programs that "Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android" is installed and that you are running Windows 8/8.1 Pro 64-bit or better, that would be appreciated. The Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android requires Hyper-V to be installed on the machine.

It also looks like by the error you provided that you may be missing some items in your Android SDK installation. Please go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk and run SDK Manager.exe as administrator and ensure that under Android 4.4.2 (API 19), both the ARM EABI v7a System Image and the Intel x86 Atom System Image are installed as well as the SDK Platform. Those are necessary for the default Google Emulator

Thanks

--Pierson

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running Windows 7 Pro SP1, does this prevent me from running the emulator? By reinstalling the VS preview I managed to get to the secondary installer I somehow missed before, however nothing changed in terms of run options. Android SDK manager shows that I have installed 4.4.2 (API 19).

Comment: Currently VS Emulator for Android is not supported on Windows 7 because Hyper-V is not supported on Windows 7. More detail on this can be found here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx under 'Current limitations' section.