# Visual Studio’s Emulator for Android not installed with VS 2015 or the Cordova CTP3

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

According to the documentation here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx

The Visual Studio Emulator for Android installs either with the Visual Studio 2015 Preview or the Cordova Tools, both of which I have installed.

However when I open my Cordova Tools created app I don't see the Visual Studio Android Emulator in the options. Hyper-V is enabled and running but there's no VS Android Emulator image.

Just to be sure I reinstalled the Cordova Tools for VS 2013, which took forever, but still no change in emulators.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you choose other emulators iOS/Windows?

Comment: Yes the other emulators are there. But Curious why the new emulator image isn't showing up.

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated in this thread - [Visual Studio Preview 2015 is missing "VS Emulator Android Phone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907629/visual-studio-preview-2015-is-missing-vs-emulator-android-phone), the Visual Studio Emulator for Android is installed with a separate installer after the main VS 2015 installed ends with the rest of the tools.

Please also notice that the Visual Studio Emulator for Android uses Hyper-V and therefore is not supported on Windows 7 or earlier. This could also be part of the problem.

To install it